# Why wont File.WriteAllText() update my file every frame?

Tags: c#, class, object, unity-game-engine, text

I am trying to create a game that follows an RPG, turn-based battle system in Unity 5.6.1. In order to do this, I am storing a bunch of variables in json files. All the json to string conversions work and return no errors. Also, I am able to change the json files with my script. My issue is that, when the script is supposed to change something, it doesn't do it until I check the script in monodevelop, so that even though it should be updating every frame, it doesn't update at all unless I look at it in monodevelop. Can anybody help me?

```
TextAsset txtAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("CombatStats", typeof(TextAsset));
string jsonString = txtAsset.text;
List<CombatStatSet> combatStatSet = JsonMapper.ToObject<List<CombatStatSet>>(jsonString);
combatStatSet [0].Strength += 1;
jsonString = JsonMapper.ToJson (combatStatSet).ToString();
jsonString = JsonFormatter.FormatJsonString(jsonString);
File.WriteAllText (Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + "CombatStats" + ".json", jsonString);
```

This is what I am using to convert my CombatStats.json file to a string and then a list of objects, modify one of the variables in one of the objects, and then convert the list of objects back into a string, format it, and write it back to the file. This works fairly well. Everything works except that update issue I mentioned before. All the code above is in the Update() function. This is the JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "Strength": 12,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    },
    {
        "Strength": 0,
        "Intelligence": 0,
        "Defense": 0,
        "Resistance": 0,
        "Accuracy": 0,
        "Agility": 0,
        "Speed": 0,
        "CurrentAP": 0,
        "CurrentHP": 0,
        "Affinity": 0,
        "Poison": 0,
        "Weakness": 0,
        "Paralysis": 0,
        "LifeStatus": 0
    }
]
```

I also want to mention that all of this was working like a charm in Unity 5.5.1. However, it stopped working correctly in Unity 5.6.1. The variable will only update when I check monodevelop, and even then it acts as if me checking it is only one frame. It should be a number skyrocketing into the hundreds, but it only goes up one every time I check it. I also have the value tied to a text box on the screen, and it only changes when I check monodevelop as well.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your `Update()` code, does it reach there?

Comment: There aren't any errors. The file is just not updating. All this is at the start of the update function, and there is a lot of stuff after it that is still working. So the Update () function works all the way through.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by **check monodevelop**. Is your `MonoBehaviour` attached to any `GameObject` in your scene? This is strange, maybe they did something from one version to another, since it was working before. Very strange, though.

Comment: try adding `Debug.Log(jsonString)` in your update method and see if that produces the correct output in the console window

Comment: Miles Kim, Do not write files every frame, not just because of performance, your app will ruin so many devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity editor only processes files in the resources folder when it is refreshed (loses and then regains focus) so if you edit a file in the resources folder, Unity wont know about it until you refresh the editor (which is what is happening when you check mono develop).

Editing a file in the resources folder at run-time doesn't really make sense, and on most platforms, once you build your application, the resources folder is not writable.

Perhaps you should use `Application.persistentDataPath` instead. You could check to see if the json file exists in `Application.persistentDataPath`, and if it doesn't, load your json text asset. From then on, only use `File.RaedAllText` and `File.WriteAllText` with the `Application.persistentDataPath` folder.

```
string jsonPath;

void Start()
{
    jsonPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/CombatStats.json";

    if (!File.Exists(jsonPath))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, Resources.Load<TextAsset>("CombatStats").text);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);

    // update your json

    File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Also, when I save it to persistentDataPath:

1. Now it's just not working at all
2. I don't know what folder it saves to

I am on Windows 10

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working at all'? I just tested it, works perfectly.

Comment: try this `Debug.log(Application.persistentDataPath)` to see the location of the folder. You shouldn't need to know where it is, thats the whole point, it will have a different location on different platforms

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I needed to know where it was so I could delete it and see if it worked. I had accidentally just put the string "lol" in the file, which messed up the Json code. Works like a charm now.